# Unresponsive Script Error in JS.erb File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

Currently I have the Below code in a js.erb file in my ruby on rails project. What is happening is that the page is becoming unresponsive when this file is being used. Sometimes the `@updates1` can have upwards of 100 records. is there a way to process the painting in the background and keep the UI responsive. With it the way it is the page becomes "locked up/unresponsive" for 10 sec to 1 minute. sometimes i get the warning of this page has become unresponsive.

My Code works just Takes A long time to process

Actual Code in the js.erb

```
var obj1 = {
    "loads": <%= raw @updates1 %>
};

var count = 0;
var tab_keys = [];

$.each(obj1["loads"], function(k, v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value) {
        count++;
        var addId = $('#' + key).dataTable().fnAddData(value);
        var theNode = $('#' + key).dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]];
        theNode.nTr.setAttribute('id','row_' + value[0]);
        $('#' + key).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        tab_keys.push(key);
    });
});



if (count > 0) {
    var message = count + " More Loads!";

    $.titleAlert(message, {
        requireBlur:false,
        stopOnFocus:false,
        duration:8000,
        interval:700
    });

    tab_keys = $.unique(tab_keys);
    $.each(tab_keys, function(k, v){
        var tab_key = v.replace(new RegExp("_load_results", "gi"), "");
        var tab = 'a[href$="#tab_' + tab_key + '"]';
        if ($(tab).parent().hasClass("ui-state-active") == true)
            $(tab).css("font-weight","bold").parent().effect( 'highlight', {color: 'Blue'}, 7000);
        else
            $(tab).css("font-weight","bold").parent().css("background","#00D9D9").effect( 'highlight', {color: 'Blue'}, 7000);
    });

    if ( $('#prefs_can_be_screen_notified').val() == "1") {
        playSound('/assets/'+$('#prefs_default_sound').val());
    }
}
```

Results of what it is doing: BTW i cut the obj1 down in length for posting on here... It can sometimes be 100+ postings...

```
var obj1 = {
    "loads": [{'25455_1431099504_load_results': ['13345499','2015-05-08 15:48:37 UTC','<abbr class=\"timeago\" title=\"2015-05-08 10:48:37\">1 minute</abbr>','Albuquerque, NM','Colorado Springs, CO','05/12','05/13','Full','Flatbed','','53']}, {'25455_1431099504_load_results': ['13345497','2015-05-08 15:48:37 UTC','<abbr class=\"timeago\" title=\"2015-05-08 10:48:37\">1 minute</abbr>','Gypsum, CO','Lincoln, NE','05/08','05/11','Full','Flatbed','','53']}]
};

var count = 0;
var tab_keys = [];

$.each(obj1["loads"], function(k, v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value) {
        count++;
        var addId = $('#' + key).dataTable().fnAddData(value);
        var theNode = $('#' + key).dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]];
        theNode.nTr.setAttribute('id','row_' + value[0]);
        $('#' + key).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        tab_keys.push(key);
    });
});



if (count > 0) {
    var message = count + " More Loads!";

    $.titleAlert(message, {
        requireBlur:false,
        stopOnFocus:false,
        duration:8000,
        interval:700
    });

    tab_keys = $.unique(tab_keys);
    $.each(tab_keys, function(k, v){
        var tab_key = v.replace(new RegExp("_load_results", "gi"), "");
        var tab = 'a[href$="#tab_' + tab_key + '"]';
        if ($(tab).parent().hasClass("ui-state-active") == true)
            $(tab).css("font-weight","bold").parent().effect( 'highlight', {color: 'Blue'}, 7000);
        else
            $(tab).css("font-weight","bold").parent().css("background","#00D9D9").effect( 'highlight', {color: 'Blue'}, 7000);
    });

    if ( $('#prefs_can_be_screen_notified').val() == "1") {
        playSound('/assets/'+$('#prefs_default_sound').val());
    }
}
```

The Above is ran from this AJax Script:

```
    if (load_search_count > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/classics/0/refresh_load_tables",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is this AJAX?  If so, it might not be the best use case for it.

Comment: Yes this is ran from an ajax script...

Comment: So there may be a better approach but I personally wouldn't use AJAX for big compute / time intensive activities like this.  No matter what you do, you will end up with a funky user experience.  I would think about redesigning as a "normal" web app and consider how you can serve users with just the information they need at each step so that you can avoid the big "crunch" if possible.  But even if that is unavoidable, better to deal with it "traditionally" than AJAX.  IMO...

Comment: There is another alternative to this... mainly this is just to add new Data to the DataTables already on the page. But i have not figured out the AJAX datatables yet to get it to work. each one of my tables are unique to different search variables and want the different results in each coresponding table...

Comment: Wait to resize your datatable at the end of all records.  Resizing on every entry is probably killing your performance.  (fnAdjustColumnSizing)  Secondly, why are you using Datatable's support for server side processing instead of shoing in all the data yourself??